# Parsing a single object JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, https

I have a JSON response like this

```
"3928593-236523632-2353253"
```

after posting some data to a api.

I am trying to assign that response to a variable.

For example var x = data; (where data is the variable set for the https response in a request call)

but this is giving a error

Now usually i would expect something like

```
[{test: '2352532352352'}]
```

and i could of cousre go var x = data.test;

When its not like this, how can i attribute the data to a variable?

Thanks

Comment: would you please share what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: `but this is giving a error` what error is that giving you?

Comment: Hi Nishanth, it gives me the error that the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your just getting a JSON encoded string back as the response, which is totally valid JSON.

```
let response = JSON.parse('"3928593-236523632-2353253"');
```

and now

```
response === "3928593-236523632-2353253"
```